# How to pass C++ source_code in paiza.io API

Tags: c++, json, api

I wanted to pass the following **C++** source_code in **paiza.io API**. Here is the link for you to check out - [PAIZA.IO API](http://api.paiza.io/docs/swagger/#!/runners/).

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello\n";
}
```

After running the session, when I want to get the details it shows the following error:-
[image]
Please help me to find the correct way to pass cpp source_code.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` is not portable, you just need `#include <iostream>`.

Comment: How are you calling the api?

Comment: Jarod24 iostream also not working

Comment: Alan Birtles you can expand those sections and see...